# PYTHON MYSQL doesn't work second time

Tags: python, mysql

Am receiving json data (from an other python script) to put inside MYSQL database, the code work fine the first time but the second time I got this error:

```
raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

For troubleshooting am sending always the same data, but it still write an error the second time.

I tried also from information found on furums to place : cur = mydb.cursor() at diferents places but I have never been able to get this code work the second time.

There is my code :

```
import mysql.connector
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="***",
  passwd="***",
  database="***"
)



def DATA_REPARTITION(Topic, jsonData):
 if Topic == "test":
  #print ("Start")
  INSERT_DEBIT(jsonData)


def INSERT_DEBIT(jsonData):

  cur = mydb.cursor()

  #Read json from MQTT
  print("Start read data to insert")
  json_Dict = json.loads(jsonData)
  debit = json_Dict['debit']
  print("I send")
  print(debit)
  #Insert into DB Table
  sql = ("INSERT INTO debit (data_debit) VALUES (%s)")
  val=debit,

  cur.execute(sql,val)

  mydb.commit()

  print(cur.rowcount, "record inserted.")

  cur.close()
  mydb.close()
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only open your database connection once, at the start of the script, and you close that connection after making the first insert.  Hence, second and subsequent inserts are failing.  You should create a helper function which returns a database connection, and then call it each time you want to do DML:

```
def getConnection():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="***",
        passwd="***",
        database="***")

    return mydb

def INSERT_DEBIT(jsonData):
    mydb = getConnection()
    cur = mydb.cursor()

    # Read json from MQTT
    # rest of your code here...

    cur.close()
    mydb.close()
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but when I try to open another connection, I get an Error 111 Connection Refused error. Can you check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69033319/python-mysql-connection-error-111-connection-refused-after-closing-previous